# Creating a game using pyglet (sprites in particular)

Tags: python, class, sprite, pyglet

Im currently in an intro coding class and for my final project, i am trying to learn the pyglet module to create a game with a picture in the background, and have a character on the left that a user can make jump, and then have jumps come from the right at a set speed that the user will jump over.  i need to use classes for the assignment, and im really having a hard time using creating a sprite class.  heres my current code:

```
import pyglet

window = pyglet.window.Window(700,700) 
image = pyglet.image.load('IMG_3315.jpg')#use 10x10 in. image
#image_2 = pyglet.image.load('IMG_3559.jpg') 

main_batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
score_label = pyglet.text.Label(text="Score: 0", x=570, y=650, batch=main_batch)
the_jump = pyglet.image.load("jumpsi.png") 

#horse = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(image_2, x = 50, y = 50)

# background_sound = pyglet.media.load(
#          'Documents/Leave The Night On.mp3',
#          streaming=False)


class Jump(pyglet.sprite.Sprite):   
    def __init__(self, img, x=0, y=0, blend_src=770, blend_dest=771, batch=None, group=None, usage='dynamic', subpixel=False):
        self.img = the_jump
        self.x = 50
        self.y = 50

    def draw(self):
        self.draw()

# verticle = Jump('verticle')

@window.event        
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    image.blit(0, 0)
    main_batch.draw()
    window = Jump()
    #horse.draw()
    #background_sound.play()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sprite = Jump()
    pyglet.app.run()
```

i know its probably wrong but everything else i have tried (using preexisting games as examples) hasn't worked either.

my current error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jumper.py", line 39, in <module>
    sprite = Jump()
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

im just really stuck and have been trying to figure this out for hours and not made any leeway.  any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much!

UPDATE:  i recently changed the code, noticing the problem that Gustav pointed out, and change the end call to

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sprite = Jump(the_jump)
    pyglet.app.run()
```

but now i get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jumper.py", line 39, in <module>
    sprite = Jump(the_jump)
  File "jumper.py", line 21, in __init__
    self.x = 50
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyglet/sprite.py", line 459, in _set_x
    self._update_position()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyglet/sprite.py", line 393, in _update_position
    img = self._texture
AttributeError: 'Jump' object has no attribute '_texture'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you exactly which line the error is in and exactly what is wrong. You are initializing the Jump class without passing in an argument for the required parameter img.

You can fix this by either changing the initialization method or your call to Jump().

[Here's an example for how to read Python's traceback.](http://cbio.ufs.ac.za/live_docs/nbn_tut/understanding_errors.html)